# Playing audio from intent - ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, audio, mediastore

I am trying to play audio with the ACTION_VIEW intent, but regardless on what type of sound file (.mp3, .3gpp etc.) I always get the same error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3007): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to        handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/recording-23363382.3gpp typ=audio/3gpp }
```

My code:

Firstly here is where I launch the activity:

```
    case R.id.largeThumbnailText:
        media_column_index = mediacursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        mediacursor.moveToPosition(lastClicked);
        mediaFileUri = Uri.parse(mediacursor.getString(media_column_index));
        media_column_index = mediacursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE);
        String mime = mediacursor.getString(media_column_index);
        Intent playAudioIntent = new Intent();
        playAudioIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        playAudioIntent.setDataAndType(mediaFileUri, mime);
        startActivity(playAudioIntent);
        break;
```

This is where I initiate the mediacursor:

```
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE };
        mediacursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null,
                null, null);
```

I do the same thing with video, so I don't see where the problem is. Might be worth mentioning that this is all done from within a fragment.

Forgot to mention I'm testing it on a HTC Sensation (android 2.3.4)

Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code

```
Intent playAudioIntent = new Intent();
playAudioIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
playAudioIntent.setDataAndType(mediaFileUri, mime);
startActivity(playAudioIntent);
```

Try something like this:

```
String movieurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Videos/Wildlife.wmv";

Intent playAudioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
playAudioIntent .setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
```

Comment: Thank you this works.
Will it work with all audio formats though?
Do you have any insight on why it is neccessary to play audio like this?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is necessary to do it this way. Have you tried using the MediaPlayer class to play music? Normally to play music I extend the application class and create a MediaPlayer object in there. Then I create methods to use the MediaPlayer.

Comment: If you want me to show you how to do it that way ask another question "How do I use MediaPlayer by extending the Application Class" and I can post the whole example. Also, send me the link if you plan on doing this.

Answer (score 1):

common error when setting wrong mime type in the intent  take this example check if it is `audio/mp3` to play mp3 audios

```
Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/abc_xyz.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/mp3"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Well i extract the mime type directly from the mediastore, I don't see how it can be wrong or do you mean that the phone itself is unaware of the correct mime type? I have also tried "audio/*" without luck:
    intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/*");